# I cannot connect postresql database, although there is database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a database using Java Spring

properties file:

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

error message:

```
2021-02-19 16:13:25.813  INFO 16315 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-19 16:13:26.864 ERROR 16315 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "student" does not exist
...
```

my postgresql:
[image]

Although I have a database named student, it says the database does not exist. Despite a lot of research, I could not solve this problem.

Note:
I did not write any code, I just wrote student class, student service and student controller and tried to connect to the database with properties and run spring boot application.

Comment: Hey there. That's indeed strange :) Do you maybe have multiple PostgreSQL instances installed in your system?

Comment: Also, watch out for whitespace: `SELECT datname, datname::bytea FROM pg_database;`

Comment: I solved the problem. The student database is connected to port 5433. I'm sending 5432  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new database on pgAdmin 4 manually. Right click on PostgreSQL under Server and Create -> Database -> write your database name. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).